# sum count function in phpmyadmin. show results in php

Tags: php

I'm new to this site , I hope someone can help me with my question. I'm not new to php but I'm still learning (enjoying it though!)
so here is my question.
I want to get a count function where it counts how many customers selected a certain faculty. If I use this in phpmyAdmin, it works perfectly and shows the result as I want it to. it shows two columns. One called Faculty and the other called count.
Faculty has a total of 8 rows and so does count of course. But how can I display this in a table? can any one shed some light!. If you can please also explain, it would be great!

```
$queryString = "select Faculty, COUNT(Faculty) as count from `response` group by Faculty Union all select 'SUM' Faulty, COUNT(Faculty) from `response`";
$result2 = queryDatabase($queryString);
echo mysql_result($result2,0);
```

last part of code does not work properly. (echo part)

thank you very much

Comment: You need to loop over the results, not just echo one field from one row.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "display this in a table"?  It sounds like it is already in a table when you say "it shows two columns… a total of 8 rows".  A table is a set of rows and colums, no?

Comment: @OP You can't echo over an array, which is what is returned as a 'row'. You can use var_dump(mysql_result($result2, 0)); however. and stop using mysql_ functions! See the big red box http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php

Comment: @PatrickQ: I think he meant an HTML `<table>`.

Comment: thanks Rocket Hazmat for clearing it out. Sorry Patrick Q for the misunderstanding. It does show a table in phpmyAdmin! Ahmad answered my question exactly and my results appear as I want them to. Thanks very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need something like this:

```
    echo "<table>";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2)){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>{$row['Faculty']}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$row['count']}</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
```